# Detecting UITouch outside of view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uitouch

I have a `UIButton` which is acting as a "confirm" button. Basically, I want it to require two taps to trigger its action, so the first time you tap it, the picture will change to an "are you sure" type image, at which point, a second tap would trigger the action.

This works fine, but I want to set it up so that tapping anywhere outside of the button resets it back to the first image again so it requires 2 taps again.

Is there any way to detect if the user touches outside of a `UIButton`; perhaps is there a way to give it "focus" and check for a focus exit?

I thought of `UITouch`, but that will only send its event to the view you are touching that responds to it.

Comment: If the second touch is on some other control (button, text field, whatever), do you want the touch to have its usual effect on that control, or be ignored entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the button's superview (probably the view controller's content view.) Set `userInteractionEnabled` to true. Put your code that resets the button in the handler for the tap gesture recognizer.

Comment: Weird, I didn't see any answers here when I started mine.  Will remove it.

Answer (score 0):

As you know you can use `UIControlEvent.touchUpInside` for when the view is pressed

If you want to see when a press is outside of a view you can you `UIControlEvent.touchUpOutside` instead

```
button.addTarget(self, action:<SELECTOR>,forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpOutside)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to get user touch outside button event

```
@interface YourViewController ()
@property NSInteger tapCount;
@property (weak) UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer;
@end
```

add `UITapGestureRecognizer`

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    self.tapCount ++;
    if (self.tapCount == 1) {
        // change button label, image here

        // add gesture gesture recognizer
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapOutSideAction)];
        [tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
        [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addGestureRecognizer:tap];
        self.gestureRecognizer = tap;
    } else if (self.tapCount == 2) {
        // tap two times

        self.tapCount = 0;
    }
}

- (void)tapOutSideAction {
    // reset button label, image here

    // remove gesture recognizer
    self.tapCount = 0;
    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] removeGestureRecognizer:self.gestureRecognizer];
}
```